# how to get specific date result in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

example i am passing this date in `$date` = 2020-12-28 15:15:53

and

in db `approve_date` = 2020-12-28 15:15:00

i am trying to get all the record of date only like this 2020-12-28

so i tried

```
public function getdatedInvoice($date)
    {
     
        $invoices = Invoice::where('user_id' , Auth::id())->where('is_approved' , 1)->whereDate('approve_date' , $date)->get();
        dd($invoices);
        return view('approved_invoices', compact('invoices'));
    }
```

but when i try to use whereDate it gives me nothing how i can get that data according to date?

Comment: Hi. try to make your `$date` in the correct format. If you are using Carbon try: 
`Carbon::instance($date)->format('Y-m-d')` or just trim the time from your `$date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by default, Laravel will only process the `approve_date` column from your database as a string, even if you set it as a `date_time` column.

To make Laravel process it as a real date instead, you need to add this to the top of your `Invoice` model:

```
class Invoice extends Model {
    protected $dates = [
        'approve_date'
    ];
}
```

Now you will be able to make date comparisons without getting weird errors.

To make your date formatted the way you want, you can go about it in 2 ways.

1. You can either set a default date formats on every date column in your model by adding this also to the model:

   ```
   protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
   ```

   https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators
2. You can also do this at runtime in your view: `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($invoice->approve_date)->format('Y-m-d') }}`

Comment: i think u are right i am not using column created_at but i tried ur code class Invoice extends Model { protected $dates = [ 'approve_date' ]; protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d'; } but it doesnot effects my output is zero if i try to get single column value

Comment: The code above should work, as long as your `approve_date` column is not `NULL` in your DB

Comment: i think u here i got 1 point some of my rows are null in approve_date because this column is created after a long time when it is needed what do u say changing null can resolve?

Comment: You can try adding `->whereNotNull('created_at');` to your query, to make sure it fetches only invoices that have `approve_date`.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'approve_date' is not a variable... you are missing the $ sign. It should be something like this:

   > $invoices = Invoice::where('user_id' ,
   > Auth::id())->where('is_approved' , 1)->whereDate('$approve_date' ,
   > $date)->get();
2. that variable is not being declared in the function;
3. After all that, you have your date like date/time and you should convert the format using (for example) Carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/